# Larger data sets with random treatment (Randomized Trial Data)

Tags: data-request, randomized-trial

We are looking for data sets which are divided into a treatment and control group and where a "treatment effect" can be identified.

It is important only that the sample is "large", since we want to be able to run computations on sub-samples. "Large" is in this context simply defined as " even with a sub-sample of the data, the main treatment effect can be identified."

- The field from which the data stems could be any (e.g. medicine, economics, biology, pol sci).
- "Treatment" should be random, binary and ideally without any stratification (simply i.i.d Bernoulli)
- It is fine (and even desired) if this data has been studied extensively in previous studies.

The more independent data sets we could get the better.

**Update/Edit**:
I feel I need to add that I placed the bounty after the first two answers were given, with  the intention of rewarding *additional* answers!

Comment: Browse your favorite economics journal for RCTs. There've been plenty over the last 15 years or so and most top econ journals have open data policies.

Comment: Not really, they are hardly ever i.i.d. Bernoulli and usually employ some form of stratification. Also sample sizes tend to be rather small. If you know a counter-example, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

If you can relax your IID Bernoulli assumption, you might check out the Tennessee STAR dataset. An R version is available in the `mlmrev` package. Further details: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlmRev/

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this before. It's not100% what I'm looking for though

Answer (score 4):

The [ReplicationWiki (that I founded) lists 3 RCTs with accessible data](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php?search=rct+accessible&go=Go&title=Special%3ASearch), and you find some further studies if you [search for "randomized"](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=randomized+%22adata%3D1%22&fulltext=Search).

What is large for you?

Comment: "large" for our purpose is loosely defined by "being able (power-wise) to run treatment effect regressions on randomly drawn subsets of the data". How exactly this will be done is still to be determined. Out of the blue I'd say at least 1'000 units of treatment assignment. But obviously that hinges on several factors. Great resource btw

Comment: Would be greatly appreciated if you could register and add the information you find if you try out the datasets. Size and description of dataset would be a valuable contribution but just endorsements by joining are also already helpful so that we can expand the database.

Comment: Glad to see that the W4G Rating Bar is still useful somewhere :-)

Comment: It's only useful if it is used, so please just do it!